# Edit %PATH% programmatically

Tags: java, batch-file, vtk

I want to run a jar file using:

```
runTime.exec(new String[]{"...\\Viewer3D.bat", arg1 ,arg2})
```

> Viewer3D.bat: java -jar CliniSys.jar %1 %2 CliniSys.jar need some dll
>   (VTK dll) that should be referenced in System %PATH% variable.

How can i edit `%PATH%` programmatically (java code,script.bat,...)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `Runtime.getRuntime().exec(String[] cmdarray, String[] envp)`.

You can put anything you want in `envp`

If you want to inherit most variables from your caller use `System.getEnv()` and then iterate over it and copy it into `envp`, and only then change whatever you need.